# Things to do before updating Android SDK tools in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm working on Android App on Eclipse, Now I see updates for Android SDK folders

> Tools
>
> Android 6.0 (API 23)
>
> Extras

In my current App I used **google-play-services_lib library copied in my workspace**
Do I need to do anything before updating my SDK ? I don't want to take a risk of losing my setup because of update.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you not need to do something special, appart to check this page
https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html
and check if something affect your proyect.

I strongly recomend you to move to Android Studio because Eclipse is deprecated now and will receive less and less features and upgrades. I know it's a little difficult right now but the pros are bigger than the cons.